What Caused "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin" Error
I am writing a Kotlin library, and I want the integration experience to be as smooth as possible. Therefore, I'm trying to understand what kind of situation would breaks library compatibility.
There's one thing that I'm still not sure of. In my experience of writing android application, sometimes I encountered the "Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is x, expected version is y" error.
My question is, in what condition will such error occur? Since it is not immediately clear to me.
Sometimes updating the kotlin-gradle-plugin to newer version works (which in my understanding, it is updating the underlying kotlin-compiler). But it doesn't make sense to me. Because in my understanding, kotlin compiles to java bytecode, which allowing the smooth interoperability with Java.
Thus, my intuition told me, the compiler should have had done its job by the time the source is compiled into binary. When a client project consumes the library, it is already plain bytecode and no kotlin compilation shall take place anymore (the kotlin compiler should just compile the new kotlin sources from the client's project and no need to recompile the library), yet the error was thrown. I feel there's a hole in my understanding here.
Any explanation related to this is appreciated.
